# How do I lift a jammed sump lid?

Tags: sump

My sump's lid hasn't been opened since years.

I want to open it, and tried pulling it with all the force I could apply but it didn't make any difference.

I tied a rope to the handles and pulled the rope, without any success.

How do I take it out?

[image: picture of the lid]

Edit:

Thanks to @Tetsujin I used a little water and scraped the sides with a knife. Repeated it for about 10 times and it came out !

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's a sump pump well?  I don't see the discharge pipe.  It looks more like a grease pit to me.

Comment: what's the deal with those circles? do they turn?

Comment: @Jasen -Those are handles used to lift the lid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressure washer and a rubber hammer.

First, blast the washer round the joint for a few minutes, then bang around the edges & corners with the rubber hammer. You could also try running a steel rule round the crack, if one will fit.
Rinse & repeat as necessary.
You might gain a bit of traction with a heavy-duty screwdriver or small jemmy bar on the widest gap. I used to carry a sacrificial screwdriver with a thinned blade tip to use as a lever in this type of situation. You often wreck them & have to replace.

Don't use a steel hammer, for obvious reasons.

tbh, you're not going to get much purchase using tiny keys like that & they don't look strong enough to use a big lever on, but for a one-off lift it doesn't seem worth buying heavier-duty keys.
Alternatively, hire a manhole cover lifter - but take those keys with you for sizing, to make sure it will fit something that small.

Manual & hydraulic…

[image]  [image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Water and a knife did the trick :)